# Portable Program Run From Archive

Tags: zip, archive, portability, rar

Are there any downsides to running a portable program from a zip/rar file? I have 20 gigabytes of portable programs that I want to sync to my cloud service. I want to sync the portable programs up as archived files. Many cloud services have problems when you upload more than 100k files, and I want to upload archives of the portable apps to circumvent any complications.

I've tried running portable apps from zip/rar files and they run just fine. But I want to know if there are any downsides to doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There are.
Running an app from an archive means, you don't extract them to a folder, instead you directly  double click on them from the window of archiver software.

When you do this, archivers simply extract them to temp folder and run them from there.
Side effects of this are;

- Antivirus etc softwares will become more suspicious to them
- Since portable apps are keeping settings in their folders, any cleaner (like ccleaner etc) software will delete your settings.
- There will be a idle time before execute since you need them to be extracted to temp file completely
- When you close and application. In second execute archiver will extract it again completely
- It will bloat your temp folder but not a big deal I think

So, why not to pack them with UPX, mpress etc. Or even you can use an app which already do the same what you do but in better way. [here is the link](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Packers-Crypters-Protectors/FilePacker.shtml)